# How can I redirect the output of a process file write?

Tags: linux, io, file-descriptor

I have a legacy app running that sends its output to log files. Rather than tail and manage those log files, I want to capture the output before it hits the disk and send it off elsewhere on the network (using syslog, or fluentd, or logstash, etc.).

Is there any way I can capture the output without changing the application code itself? I do have the option of changing the process startup, so I can "wrap" it.

I thought of a few options:

- Named pipe - it would work, but subject to pipe buffer and broken pipe limitations.
- Standard redirect - really only works for known file descriptors, i.e. stdin, stdout, stderr / 0,1,2

Is there any sane way to interject my program so that the app thinks it is still writing to /var/log/myapp.log but instead is being sent to my log controller which can then do as it wishes?

Comment: "pipe buffer and broken pipe limitations" - I don't see any problems with that. could you elaborate on it?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath you are not concerned with it? Think of a system pumping out thousands of log messages per second. With disk-based log file, it causes significant disk i/o and space usage. If I can capture it and send it off-host immediately, I solve both of those. But thousands of messages per second will overwhelm /dev/log or any other pipe, no?

Comment: it shouldn't. if in doubt, test it. note: it's a pipe, not a disk *based* file.

Comment: Of course, that is the idea!

Comment: If the disk is not able to keep up with the logger, then the network will never be able to do so too.

Comment: @Mr.Me: not true, networks have a lot wider bandwidth.

Comment: Pipes have a limited-size buffer. But it doesn't overflow when full, it'll only put the writer on the wait queue (=make the writer block).

Comment: @Mr.Me not necessarily. The disk is constrained by throughput in MB/s and iops. With thousands of small messages per second, MB/s is not an issue, iops is. Also, once I get it into something like syslog-ng or rsyslog, I can control it and send them out in batches

Comment: Not sure making the write block is any better, but that is a business decision, right?

Comment: yepp. For example, you can move the writer to a separate thread, so it will never block the other threads. But then why don't send to network directly from there? Well, modularity comes to mind...

Comment: Of course, if I cannot change the app, I cannot do that.

Comment: Your app won't get blocked if you've got a reader that keeps reading from the pipe fast enough.

Comment: if neccessary, do some fine-tuning to avoid temporary bottlenecks - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer

Comment: @Mr.Me: not sure what needs to be clarified.. how do you propose to do 1Gb/s or 10Gb/s throughput with a plain disk? because that's what ethernet networks offer.. (well, 90% if packages aren't tiny)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath no worries, I was under the impression this is no mobile for some reason, read io tag as iOS, my bad .

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Note that even a 10Gb/s (10 giga-*bits* per second) can be accomodated by modern fiber channel storage, especially if striped across several HBAs - thats only about 1GB (1 giga-*byte* per second), which should be easily manageable even with 2 8 giga-bit FC HBAs...

Comment: Ah, yes, but who wants to pay 6 figures just for the storage? Much better to have an ephemeral app on local disk that can be recreated instantly via Docker or VMs, and have the logs straight out.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I was wondering why people thought mobile. Now I get it! "io" as in "input/output" was read as iOS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use named pipes.
The pipe buffer size isn't something you should need to worry about and you shouldn't get SIGPIPES if the reader end doesn't die (or close the connection early).

Your reader could be as simple as

```
<named_pipe nc some_address some_port &
```

If you were to kill it while your writer was writing to it, the writer would get a SIGPIPE.

As for the buffer size concern, as long as `nc`ing to `some_address someport` is faster or as fast as the rate at which data is being written to the named pipe, the writer process won't get blocked. If the writer is faster, it will when the buffer fills up. (But then, writing to disk or the network will get you blocked too).

You don't have to worry about the system-determined pipe buffer size; simply modify buffering at the reader end of the pipe (e.g., you can set the TCP output buffer size of nc, which will have the same effect as increasing the pipe buffer size) if the pipe buffer size is too small for you.

If you're launching the programs from bash and your app takes the log file as an argument, you can simply give it `>( nc some_address some_port)`, which will create an anonymous named pipe for you.

Comment: Oooh. Like. I need to check if the logfile is hardcoded in. But if not, then the best thing to do is just use it in the argument. Would that work for env vars as well?

Comment: The anonymous named pipes are only open for the current pipeline `foo=>(cat) echo hi > $foo` could theoretically work, but in practice it doesn't; you'll need to use real named fifos if you're passing args via the environment.

Answer (score 0):

On linux you can create a `chroot` environment for your process. All file access is now local to your given root path which enables you to prepare pipes/fifos to all files you want to replace. This may take a while to get the whole environment running but it makes it possible to run the process in a fully controlled environment.

Answer (score 0):

As PSkocik said, you could try using 'nc' to send off log right away, but keep in mind 'nc' stops itself when it receives EOF character. You could try using tail to follow log and send it to remote host

```
tail -f named-pipe-log-file|nc remote-host port
```

On remote host, have 'nc' running in listen mode,writing into local log using `'nc -lkd port > log'`